# Knockout Computed Observable Not Updating after reading stored value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, computed-observable

I am using a Knockout computed observable to store data from my users in the following fashion:

```
var DummyClass = (function() {
   userPrefs = ko.observable({
      value1: 0,
      value2: 0,
      value3: 0});

   commonPrefs = ko.observable({
      required: false
   });

   var userSettings = ko.computed(function() {
      var value1 = userPrefs().value1;
      var value2 = userPrefs().value2;
      var value3 = userPrefs().value3;

      if (typeof value1 === 'undefined') {
         value1 = 0;
      }

      value1 = String(value1);

      if (value1.length === 0) {
         if (commonPrefs().required === true) {
            value2 = 0;
            value3 = 1;
         }
         else {
            value2 = 1;
            value3 = 0;
         }
      }

      return {
         value1: value1,
         value2: value2,
         value3: value3
      };
   }
}
```

If I retrieve value1 by using dummyClass.userSettings().value1 elsewhere in my code, or update it with new values, any further attempts to update the data stored in userSettings via dummyClass.userSettings({value1: 1,value2: 2,value3: 3}) (for example) will no longer work, and whatever values I have in userSettings will remain that way unless I reload my web application.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points:

- Your `userPrefs` is observable, but its properties are not. So KO will not know whether they have been changed. One thing to remember with KO is you have to make everything explicitly observable. Though in this case, if you're always updating the entire object, you would get away with that.
- A computed variable, by default, is *not writable*. You have to explicitly make it writable if that's what you want, but it's not something you would typically do (at least in all my years of working with KO I only ever once came across a valid use case for having a writable computed; of course, it might be a matter of personal preference!).
- `typeof value1 = 'undefined'` is an assignment and not a comparison, so that won't work.

Here's some example code that does what you're looking for (I think):

```
function ViewModel() {
    var vm = this;
    
    vm.userPrefs = ko.observable({
        value1: 0,
        value2: 0,
        value3: 0
    });
    
    vm.commonPrefs = {
        required: false
    };
    
    vm.userSettings = ko.pureComputed({
        read () {
            var value1 = vm.userPrefs().value1 || 0;
            var value2 = vm.userPrefs().value2;
            var value3 = vm.userPrefs().value3;

            if (value1 === 0) {
                if (vm.commonPrefs.required === true) {
                    value2 = 0;
                    value3 = 1;
                } else {
                    value2 = 1;
                    value3 = 0;
                }
            }

            return {
                value1,
                value2,
                value3
            };
        },
        write(newVal) {
            vm.userPrefs(newVal);
        }
    });
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/fqznpexg/

But the writable computed isn't really necessary, because you could just manipulate `userPrefs` directly: `vm.userPrefs({ value1: 1, value2: 2, value3: 3})`.

Comment: The question is here for 16 hours, and we posted answers in the same minute, such a coincidence :)

Comment: Sorry about the assignment, that was a typo!  Updated my question and I'll look at both your suggestions!

Comment: I actually do send an entirely new object to the computed observable elsewhere in my code, and it still does not update the values when I do this.  Furthermore, I actually tried making my computed observable writable and that unfortunately did not work either.  Thanks for the suggestions tho!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set a value to the computed field "userSettings", but you have only defined the "read" function (without arguments). In order to set some values via this property, you should define a "write" function. See [computed writable docs](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html).

Besides it, beware that if you have an observable field with a backing object (e.g. DummyClass.userPrefs), you should provide a new object to the "observable" function in order to update the field.

For example:

`DummyClass.userPrefs().value1 = 1`  - will not trigger an update for DummyClass.userPrefs

`DummyClass.userPrefs({value1: 1, value2: 2, value3: 3})` - will trigger an update

Comment: I forgot to mention, but I do in fact send a new object every time I update userPrefs.  My question will be updated.

Comment: I want to highlight one more time, that if you want to update anything via dummyClass.userSettings, you should design it as a writable computed (add a write function to it)